# expansible text with contenteditable does not push with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, contenteditable, html

I want that a span expands automatically when text is entered. This works with all browsers but IE (v9 tested) where the text overwrites the phrase after ("should push the text.").

Is there a remedy? It seems that it is a refresh problem. the layout engine should issue a refresh.
**Edit**: in compatibility mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
```

it works so it is a fresh IE9 issue. Workaround?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  </head>
<body>
      <div id="link-widget-container"> 
          <p>this "
                <span id="goal" contenteditable="true" 
                      spellcheck="false" 
                      class="input-widget">
                          test
                 </span>
               " should push this text. 
          </p>
      </div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered placing the text that is to be pushed inside a span of its own:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  </head>
<body>
      <div id="link-widget-container"> 
          <p>this 
                <span id="goal" contenteditable="true" 
                      spellcheck="false" 
                      class="input-widget">
                          "test"
                 </span>
                 <span>should push this text.</span>
          </p>
      </div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

You might also want to use a float:left CSS property on your spans to ensure they flow together nicely.